# why setImage() doesn't change my ImgView in JavaFx?

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview, scenebuilder

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ChooseScheme extends Application{

    GUIBoard board = new GUIBoard();
    Stage primaryStage;
    Integer totalScheme = 26;

//these are the imgs I want to change, in the fxml file they have their own path but with the method chooseRandomImgs(), 

    @FXML
    ImageView scheme1 = new ImageView();

    @FXML
    ImageView scheme2 = new ImageView();

    @FXML
    ImageView scheme3 = new ImageView();

    @FXML
    ImageView scheme4 = new ImageView();

    public void launchChooseScheme() throws Exception {

        start(new Stage());
    }

//standard method, it runs and open the scene

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        Parent ChooseScheme;
        ChooseScheme = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("GUIFiles/ChooseScheme.fxml"));

        Stage stage = new Stage();

        chooseRandomImgs();

        stage.setTitle("Choose Scheme");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(sgChooseScheme, 600, 400));
        stage.show();

    }

//this method should change my img

    private void chooseRandomImgs() {
        int countImages = totalScheme;
        int imageNumber = (int) (Math.random() * countImages);

        System.out.println(imageNumber);
        Image schemeImage = new Image("GUIfiles/imgs/schemecard/val5/"+ imageNumber + ".jpg");

        scheme1.setImage(schemeImage);
    }
}
```

The Img path is correct. When I run the class doesn't change the ImgView `scheme1`; instead it remains the Img I set on SceneBuilder, every time I run the code never shows the new Img. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance of `ChooseScheme` is a different one than the one that is used with the fxml (assuming the `fx:controller` attribute is set to the appropriate value).

You always initialize the `ImageView` fields, but if the instance of `ChooseScheme` is not used with a fxml, the instances are never added to a scene. (In fact the instances created by the initializer are never added to a scene, but for the controller used with a fxml the initial values are replaced during load.)

It is never a good idea to initialize fields that are supposed to be injected from the fxml. This just fixes the `NullPointerException` that may be thrown.

Using the `Application` class as controller is not a good idea either.

Depending on where you want to determine the random images, you need to use one of the approaches presented here [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml) .

Alternatively you could do this from the `initialize` method of the controller. This method is run during `load` after all objects have been injected.

### Example

#### Controller class

```
package mypackage;

...

public ChooseSchemeController {

    private static final Random random = new Random();
    private static final int TOTAL_SCHEME = 26; // you don't want to use a wrapper type here

    @FXML
    private ImageView scheme1;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        chooseRandomImage(scheme1);
    }

    private void chooseRandomImage(ImageView iv) {
        int imageNumber = random.nextInt(TOTAL_SCHEME);

        System.out.println(imageNumber);
        Image schemeImage = new Image("GUIfiles/imgs/schemecard/val5/"+ imageNumber + ".jpg");

        iv.setImage(schemeImage);
    }

}
```

#### GUIFiles/ChooseScheme.fxml

```xml
<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="mypackage.ChooseSchemeController">
    <children>
        <ImageView fx:id="scheme1"/>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: thank you a lot, you were really clear, it worked and I learnt something!