# Java getResourceAsStream NullpointerException when loading image for JavaFX ImageView

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have the following project setup (Maven Project):

[project setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oejqw.png)

And the absolute path:
C:\Users\jenny\IdeaProjects\gameapp\client\src\main\resources\images\game\black_market.png

This code throws a Nullpointerexception:

```
    private void setUpImage(ImageView image){
    Platform.runLater(()->{
        var url = getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/game/black_market.png");
        System.out.println(url.toString());
        Image img = new Image(url);
        image.setImage(img);
    });
}
```

It's probably because the filepath is incorrect but I don't really know how to fix it on my own. I've tried for the last 2-3 hours researching similar problems on Stackoverflow.

The ImageView that gets passed on this function is a reference to an ImageView. My function should load the image and put it into the passed ImageView. To be honest, I don't actually know if that will work since Java is pass by value.

Comment: Try using `var url = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/game/black_market.png");` instead.  A relative path will look within the current package for the resource, where as using `/` will look at the top of the class path.  Also, unzip the resulting JAR file and check the images are been included within the JAR file

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. I've tried it but still get:
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found.

The Images are included in the compiled classes/JAR.

Answer (score 0):

[why setImage() doesn't change my ImgView in JavaFx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802563/why-setimage-doesnt-change-my-imgview-in-javafx)

This question fixed it. I've noticed that the @FXML annotations were missing. Adding them fixed the entire problem.

```
@FXML
private void setUpImage(ImageView image){
    Platform.runLater(()->{
        Image img = new Image("/images/game/black_market.png");
        image.setImage(img);
    });
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you have that code wrapped in a `Platform.runLater` call?

Comment: @Slaw You're completly right that code is redundant since I'm in the GUI Thread/Controller class.